# Styling polygons based on data from column

Tags: qgis, polygon, symbology, style

I have a multipolygon layer in QGIS 3.4.

[image]

Attribute table looks like this.

[image]

I want to style each polygon based on column `"Percent Ar"`.

When I open Layer `Properties >> Symbology`, I choose *"Graduated"* from the symbol menu. I think that's where I have to go to accomplish what I want...

Anyway, there's nothing in the "Column" field. When I type `"Percent Ar"`  the text turns red. If I click outside the field, the text disappears.

[image]

How do I assign the color fill for each polygon based on the `"Percent Ar"` column?

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is that all of your columns have been imported as text fields, and so they are not recognized as being numeric. You can tell this by the fact that all of contents of the cells in the attribute table are left-justified instead of right-justified.

Create a new field by opening the attribute table, starting an edit session, and clicking on the "New Field" button. Set the field's value to `to_real("Percent Ar")`. This field should then appear in the column selection box.

As a side note, this happens quite often when data is imported from a CSV or other text-based format. Anita Graser wrote a guide on how to deal with it more effectively [here](https://anitagraser.com/2011/03/07/how-to-specify-data-types-of-csv-columns-for-use-in-qgis/).

Comment: you can also type the "E" and type the same expression `to_real("Percent Ar")` without adding any new field.

Comment: @snaileater Where would I type that?

Comment: Go to the attribute table and click on the "Add Column" button.

Comment: Turns out I can type `to_real("Percent Ar")` into the column field. If you add that to your answer, I'll check it off. That's the solution I used.

Comment: I added the part about clicking on the "Add Field" button.

Comment: @ Username instead of creating a new field insert the formula by clicking the E button ("greek e icon")